# macOS 11.6.3: Emacs acts like control, meta keys are sticking; how to diagnose?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, gui-emacs, keyboard

I'm a longtime GNU Emacs and macOS (and GNU Emacs *on* macOS) user, on a US Gov't owned MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) running macOS 11.6.3.

For the last few weeks, GUI versions of Emacs are acting as if the Control or Meta key was being held down for a few seconds after it was released. Needless to say, this makes editing particularly painful.

This has happened with both the MacPorts and emacsformacosx dot com builds of Emacs 28.1, *and* with older Emacsen running in Linux virtual machines!

Emacs running in the macOS Terminal app is not affected.

The problem does not affect other Mac apps, *unless* I am switching context from Emacs to some other app.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? How can I chase down the cause of this problem?

Comment: If you build Emacs from sources, you can define `NS_TRACE` and run the Emacs app in the terminal. All events will be printed, so you can see exactly what happens.

Comment: Are your keys physically sticking? Have you accidentally enabled "sticky keys" (System Prefs -> Accessibility -> Keyboard -> Hardware)?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior w/ an external keyboard? There is _some_ combination of modifier keys that _sometimes_ lock "on" for me when I hold them down too long. When it happens I can never figure out what I did or how to undo it. I have to unplug/replug the keyboard to reset them. I think in my case it's more of a keyboard firmware issue than a macOS/software issue.

Comment: Sticky Keys and Slow Keys are turned off. The keyboard doesn't seem to be broken; if I watch the Keyboard Viewer, I can see the Control key up event is not delayed.

I do have an external keyboard attached to a KVM switch, that is worth a try.